# Unable to do code Code first Migration when deployed to azure web role

Tags: azure-sql-database, entity-framework-6, azure-web-roles

When I deploy my application to Azure Web role, I expect code first migration to run, and unfortunately that doesn't happen.  When I run the application in the emulator, the code first migration happens fluently & I do not encounter any issues.

I have custom ClaimsAuthenticationManager, and that where EFF context is called first. I wonder if context is not available there.

I am using lastest MVC, with Azure SDK 2.4, & Eff 6.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF does not run migrations when deploying to SQL Azure, instead, if you check the appropriate option, a section should be added to the web.config that would register MigrateDatabaseToLastetVersion initializer, that *should* update your db first time you are using it. This is not the experience you are seeing?